# Why aren't my integer columns available for graduated styling?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, style

I have a layer with graduated styling based on an integer column. When I duplicate the layer to make a similar styling based on another integer column, none of the columns are available for graduated styling of the duplicate layer.

The layer is a shapefile and all the fields of all the integer columns have a value.
The same problem occurs when I save as a new shapefile, add it and try to apply graduated styling.

Why isn't it showing up in the list?

Comment: what are the column names? I had an issue with the name being all numeric the other day.

Comment: OmmInt, BelInt and SkyInt.

Comment: What QGIS version are you using? Might sound strange but have you tried creating new integer fields, copying the values over and then try and use those fields for styling. I was forced to do this once for an older QGIS version (can't remember which it was).

Comment: I'm using 2.8.9. 
Your method did work, @Joseph, but it made the original layer lose its graduated styling options.

Comment: @Henrik - Sounds like a bug, you should probably consider upgrading to QGIS 2.14. I couldn't replicate your issue with 2.14.1 =)

Comment: I'll try that when this project I'm working on is done. Thanks!

Comment: @Joseph, so I managed to replicare the issue in 2.14.2. However, I tried putting the integer values into real number fields, which seems to solve the problem. Now I can copy the layer freely and the real number fields appear as options for graduated on all copies of the layer.

Comment: @Henrik - Awesome, glad you found a solution. Consider posting your comment as an **answer** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason integer fields aren't always recognized as valid for graduated styling. Putting the integer values into real number fields solves the problem. Now I can copy the layer freely and the real number fields appear as options for graduated on all copies of the layer.